# How to make a html request without changing current URL?

Tags: html, request

Think of it like a login page. You type in all the credentials and click login. But I wanna check the username and password are correct or not and they will be in my database. So i use a API to communicate. And then u click login then through JavaScript i send a request but then the browser totally changes the page. All i want is the result but the browser changes the URL. Is there a way to do it?. Currently I am letting the page redirect back, its working fine but it just looks ugly.

Sorry i didn't include any code, I thought Code isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to guess without seeing the code.

Anyway, are you using `fetch`?

`Fetch` is used if a browser should not navigate to a new page. The response is processed using Javascript instead.

Take a closer look at the fetch API, I think it can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for u r answer. After a few head-scratches and some googling i found out using AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is my way to go.

Comment: Good to hear that! :)